# Hide rows if name is Sam and Ticket name Accela in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Imagine we have three columns in Excel (No. Name Ticket) and we need to hide from the spreadsheet the user name Sam and ticket name ACCELA. I created the following code but it does not work.

```
Sub Hide_Rows()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("A2:C37")
        If c.Value = "Sam" Then
            If c.Value = "ACCELA" Then
                c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
            End If
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

I also tried the following and did not work:

```
Sub Hide_Rows_Toggle() 
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("A2:C37").Cells
        If c.Value = "Sam" And c.Value = "ACCELA" Then
            'The following line changes the hidden property to
            'the opposite of it's current setting for the row.
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = Not c.EntireRow.Hidden
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Any help please.

Comment: in you second you want `Or` instead of `And`.  `c` cannot be both `Sam` and `ACCELA` at the same time.

Comment: Scott Craner, Is it another way to make the condition for both when name Sam and ticket ACCELA, because I want to hide when both condition are true.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
Sub Hide_Rows()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' change
Dim unionRange As Range

Dim c As Range

ws.Range("B2:B37").EntireRow.Hidden = False

For Each c In ws.Range("B2:B37")
    If c = "Sam" And c.Offset(, 1) = "ACCELA" Then
        If Not unionRange Is Nothing Then
            Set unionRange = Union(unionRange, c)
        Else
           Set unionRange = c
        End If
    End If
Next c

If Not unionRange Is Nothing Then
    unionRange.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @ScottCraner Again to the rescue

Comment: Based on OP's comment I believe it should be `And` not `Or`.

Comment: Thank you QHarr, but the only problem with this is hide from both columns Sam and ACCELA, I want to hide when in column Emp is Sam and at the same time Ticket is ACCELA.

Comment: Edited. That part felt ambiguous to me hence my comment about And versus Or. And put in and +1 to Scott again :-)

Comment: Thank you Scott, it works using And instead of Or. Thank you QHarr too.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `AutoFilter`

```
Sub Hide_Rows()
    Dim rngToHide As Range
    With Worksheets("mySheetName").Range("B1:C37") ' change "mySheetName" to yur actual sheet name
        .EntireRow.Hidden = False
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Sam"
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="ACCELA"
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then Set rngToHide = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
    If Not rngToHide Is Nothing Then rngToHide.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Sub
```